# Is there any way reading from store not from Component in React-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm using React and Redux in my app as main architecture frameworks. And I want to create a simple utility script which sends requests to all IPs written in `store` adding some headers to them. I use code like this for `store` connection in `Component`:

```
export default connect(() => {
    return {};
})(MyClass);
```

But how do I connect to `store` in a simple script, not in `Component`?

Comment: To use `store.dispatch()` to dispatch an action to store?

Comment: @AndreLee I don't need to dispatch action, I just want to read some data from `store`.

Comment: `const someData = store.getState();`?

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, that's really what I need. Post this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a reference to a store, you can get the current state via

```
store.getState()
```